# How to show changelog of Angular PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have an Angular PWA App with angular 13. every works very well. But I thought it would be nice if I show the user a changelog of the new version. But I don’t know how I can do it.
Did some ones do something like that?
I am looking forward to hear from you.

Thanks !

Comment: This is a very general question that is hard to answer. What have you tried so far? The general idea would be that you need to store the changelog text somewhere - maybe a database. And save it as html string and then read the html string to a page?

Comment: Where the string is saved is the second point. I don’t know how I show the popup on update. 
Before the update from Angular 11 to 13 I got a message, that’s a new version is available. That’s won’t work with the new Angular. 

if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      this.swUpdate.versionUpdates.pipe(
        filter((evt: any): evt is VersionReadyEvent => evt.type === 'VERSION_READY'),
        map((evt: any) => {
          console.info(`currentVersion=[${evt.currentVersion} | latestVersion=[${evt.latestVersion}]`);
          this.modalVersion = true;
        }),
      );
    }